# How to align the icons to the right of the text with the icon list elementor module?

Tags: css, wordpress, elementor

I would like to Align the icons to the right of the text with the module "icon list elementor", there is no option for this can be a css solution?

[icon list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DeZRE.png)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You are correct, by saying that there is no option for that -

But in you module, you can achieve it by applying the following css.

```
selector .elementor-icon-list-item{
    display:flex;
}
selector .elementor-icon-list-icon{
    order:2;
}
```

This would make your list have the icon at the end, and you can then toy around with positioning.

Comment: It works very well thank you. Is it possible to add a padding between the text and the icon?

Comment: @5jv, well yes - You can basically do whatever you want with the CSS selectors above :)

Comment: Here's another way to do this so that the icons are fully right aligned: 

.elementor-icon-list-items {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: flex-end;
}

.elementor-icon-list-item {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    width: 100%;
}

.elementor-icon-list-icon {
    order: 2;
    margin-left: 5px;
}

.elementor-icon-list-text {
    order: 1;
    text-align: left; 
}

Comment: Or, if your list is comprised of links and not just text, you could use this CSS: .elementor-icon-list-items {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: flex-end;
}

.elementor-icon-list-item {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    width: 100%;
}

.elementor-icon-list-icon {
    order: 2;
    margin-left: 5px;
    margin-left: auto;
}

.elementor-icon-list-text {
    order: 1;
    text-align: left;
    margin-left: 5px;
}