# How can I change alignment of specific icons in Elementor Icon List widget?

Tags: css, icons, elementor

I'm using the Elementor Icon List widget. The default icon alignment is to the left of the text.

I have several icons in my list (example: i.fa-arrow-right, i.fa-arrow-up, and i.fa-arrow-left. However, I only want to change the alignment of **one** of the icons (i.fa-arrow-right) in the list to the right.

I saw [another post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63579299/how-to-align-the-icons-to-the-right-of-the-text-with-the-icon-list-elementor-mod/63579647#63579647?newreg=bfa8189ed74643078871ee3dea927883) on how to align icons to the right and the code (below) works great. However, it aligns **all** of the icons in the list to the right.

```
selector .elementor-icon-list-item{
display:flex;
}
selector .elementor-icon-list-icon{
order:2;
}
```

I tried using the same code and replacing *.elementor-icon-list-icon* in one/other/both line(s) of the code with i.fa-arrow-right and it doesn't work.